# How would I implement a next and previous button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am using plain JavaScript and JQuery in my program. I have a start button that just lets the program run freely.

```
<button class="button is-link" id= "start"> Start </button>
```

```
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
        step1();
        step2();
        step3();
        step4();
        step5();  
    })

function step1() {
   some action
}
function step2() {
   some action
}
function step3() {
   some action
}
function step4() {
   some action
}
function step5() {
   some action
}
```

How would I also include a next and previous button where I can show each function separately and go back and forth between them?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not a new or unique thing you're attempting to do.  Please edit your question and add in the relevant JS code segment, and then explain 1) what results you are getting that are not desired and 2) what you expect to be happening

Comment: It'll be easier to use switch OR create an array of the functions .. `let step = [],step[1]=function(){....},step[2]=function(){....} .....` then use the buttons to go -back and +forth by step number

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there isn't any jQuery in your code (keep it that way) :)

Secondly, if the page isn't reloading, then you should attach a single event listener like:

```
var step = 0;
ele.addEventListener(function() {
// basically store which step you're on and the click adjusts the step
// and then calls the function associated with that step
    step++;
    doNextStep(step);
});
```

Comment: Something tells me they wouldn't know what to do with the `step`, perhaps include an example what to do in `doNextStep` too...

Comment: I mean, I can't just make it up, there's basically no code to do examples with. // Some action is basically it

Comment: Sorry, I have JQuery inside the functions!

Comment: Ah ok. Basically I'm saying make a single event handler and just everytime they click a button, you figure out what step you're at and do whatever you need to do on each click.

Comment: @vanowm you're right but I can try it.

Comment: @KaibutsuX it's just a few innerHTML and .style.cssText calls but I can include more specific examples if that helps.

Comment: @KaibutsuX makes sense let me try thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple switch case will be helpful.

```
<div id="text">Click start to run the app!</div>
<button class="button is-link" id= "start" onclick="start()"> Start </button>
<button class="button is-link" id= "next" onclick="next()"> Next </button>
<button class="button is-link" id= "previous" onclick="previous()"> Previous </button>
```

```
<script>
        var step = 0;

        function start() {
            step = 1;
            handleStep();
        }

        function next() {
            step++;
            handleStep();
        }

        function previous() {
            if (step > 0)
                step--;
            handleStep();
        }

        function handleStep() {
            switch (step) {
                case 1:
                    step1();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    step2();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    step3();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    step4();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    step5();
                    break;

                default:
                    step1();
                    // Go to the first step  or any other logic as you want
                    break;
            }
        }


        function setText(text) {
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;
        }

        function step1() {
            setText("Step 1");
        }
        function step2() {
            setText("Step 2");
        }
        function step3() {
            setText("Step 3");
        }
        function step4() {
            setText("Step 4");
        }
        function step5() {
            setText("Step 5");
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: I've tried this and it is not working in my code.

Comment: Updated with working code. Please check again.